# Getting a filename of screen captured file

Tags: microsoft-onenote, evernote, print-screen

Is it possible to get filename of screen captured file in OneNote or in Evernote?

The capture only saves the date, but I want the title of the document also.

Comment: Is it an attachment within ON/EN? Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: Not really, attachment is a file itself. If I need to have some part from that file, how I am supposed to remember later for where I got that part (screen capture)? I need file name I guess.